# Is there a better way to index dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python and dataframes.  I was wondering if there's a better way to do something like this:

```
df['Datetime'] = df.index
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df['id'] = df.index
df.index = df['Datetime']
df.drop('Datetime', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I need an ID/index column so I can use it in mathematical formulas (`sin(2*pi*id)` works better than `sin(2*pi*datetime)`).

Is there an easier (Pythonic) way to generate it without having to move columns around?

Update:

```
print(df.index)
print(df['id'])
```

Outputs:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-07', '2013-01-08',
               '2013-01-09', '2013-01-10', '2013-01-11', '2013-01-14',
               '2013-01-15', '2013-01-16', 
               ...
               '2014-01-20', '2014-01-21', '2014-01-22', '2014-01-23',
               '2014-01-24', '2014-01-27', '2014-01-28', '2014-01-29',
               '2014-01-30', '2014-01-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=282, freq=None, tz='UTC')
2013-01-03 00:00:00+00:00      0
2013-01-04 00:00:00+00:00      1
2013-01-07 00:00:00+00:00      2
2013-01-08 00:00:00+00:00      3
2013-01-09 00:00:00+00:00      4
2013-01-10 00:00:00+00:00      5
2013-01-11 00:00:00+00:00      6
2013-01-14 00:00:00+00:00      7
```

Comment: You don't need to `drop/set` the index, you can pass the index as a param anyway so `np.sin(2*pi*df.index)` should work, also use `set_Index` and `reset_index(drop=True)` instead of what you're trying to do

Comment: Can you provide some sample input/output data for what you mean by "use it in mathematical formulas", and how you're currently doing the process?  It doesn't sound like you should need to be manipulating the index to do this, but it's unclear without a specific example.

Comment: @EdChum thanks for telling me about `set_Index`; I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @root the index are Datetime objects and so I can't plug them into a formula like `sin(2*pi*[2016-05-20])` vs `sin(2*pi*1)`.  My end goal is to plot a sine wave overlay.  I've updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pd.DataFrame` to re-construct the desired DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2009-1-1', periods=4))
df['Datetime'] = df.index
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df['id'] = df.index
df.index = df['Datetime']
df.drop('Datetime', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

is equivalent to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2009-1-1', periods=4))
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(len(df))}, index=df.index)
#             id
# 2009-01-01   0
# 2009-01-02   1
# 2009-01-03   2
# 2009-01-04   3
```

Or, as [A L points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355592/is-there-a-better-way-to-index-dataframes/37355659?noredirect=1#comment62227254_37355659), you could simply use

```
df['id'] = np.arange(len(df))
```

Comment: thanks this is what I ended up doing `df['id'] = np.arange(len(df))`

Comment: Ah yes, that's even simpler.